# How to insert html from file into oracle apex page

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

**Problem scenario:**

In my apex application, i have some html code which i am inserting into apex page as static content which is working file.. but this code is also used in different pages, for that i have to copy same code and paste into static content region of very page where i want that code.

**goal:**
i want to place this code into application static file and use file content into static content region of the page.

I have tried *[html import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports)* to solve this issue but not working.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your code does nor Apex version you use, but - consider putting it onto **Page 0** (in lower versions) or **Global Page** (in recent ones) (note that you have to create exactly "Global Page" - choose it from list of available page types, otherwise it won't work as expected if you just use "page number = 0" for other page types).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I am using apex 5.1 version